# How do I iterate through my directory to append files with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pathlib

Im trying to append files where if a value is NaN in a column then it should append it as 0.0. I tried -

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/bc/Desktop/Folder') 

files_with_empty_cells = []

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):

    df=pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|')
    df['confidence']=df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.0)
```

This does make the particular cell into 0.0. but only for one csv file. I want it to append all csv where there is a nan value in that particular column.

My df looks like-
[image]

So as u can see confidence for the last row of the transcript is NaN. there are multiple files that have this issue and I just want my script to loop through all files in my directory and append the blank(NaN) cells in each csv under confidence column with 0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to do something to the `df` after performing the `replace` function.

E.g.

```
for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|')
    df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.0)
    df.to_csv(file, index=False)  # overwrites the existing file
```

Comment: that only does it for one file though. What about all the files i have in the directory with an NaN under confidence column

Comment: you'd still use the loop but just add `df.to_csv(file, index=False)` at the end of the loop

Comment: (btw @Daren i suggest including `index=False`)

Comment: Thanks @tdy! The `to_csv` is just an example :) @Lodu Band can modify it according to what's required

Comment: @Daren i would mark this correct, however, the final appended csv has an additional unnamed column which has  serial numbers. How can this be ommited instead of deleting the column manually?

Comment: @tdy thank you so much for the index-False suggestion. You are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/bc/Desktop/Folder') 

files_with_empty_cells = []

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):

    pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|').replace({'confidence ':{np.nan: 0.0}}).to_csv(file)
```

Comment: master, I will be your padawan!

Comment: @LoduBand happy coding ~ :-)

Comment: This works. my only  rookie question is,where can i specify it to fill 0.0 only for NaN cells under the confidence column. Because my only worry is, your code will make NaNs under all columns 0.0

Comment: hi, thanks for your update. unfortunately,another issue i see is that, after the script runs, the final appended csv has an additional unnamed column which has the serial numbers. How can this be ommited instead of deleting the column manually?

Comment: @LoduBand adding , index=False when output csv ~